# Videos in Storage sense taking memory-Unable to find

Tags: lumia-520

my Lumia 520: storage sense (phone) shows 2.73 GB videos. But when you to manage-> my videos says nothing to show.
 How to delete this videos (where they exist) and improve phone memory?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out **Photos** app. Your videos must be there. I often suffer with similar situation in my Lumia 535. Compare these screenshots with your phone's situation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then @arvind please accept the answer so that other people suffering with the same problem might find it useful